# XCode: iOS Compatibility Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios5

I am working on an app using XCode 4.2 and test it on an iPad with iOS5 but when i tried to open my file on XCode 4.0 and run it on an iPad with iOS4 it's not working it says that i need an iOS5.

What should i do regarding this issue?

Comment: What is your target version for the project?  Check your prefix for another statement that says you'll need iOS 5 too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your project name in the left pane, select the 'Build Settings' tab, under 'iOS deployment target' select 4.0.

[image: deployment target]

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are facing this is maybe because your project and target might be set to:

```
Base SDK: Latest iOS (iOS 5.0)
```

And also check in the info tab by selecting your project, it might be like this:

```
iOS Deployment Target: (5.0)
```

Comment: well, don't forget to check Apple LLVM Compiler too if try to create an app for the older iOS version...